# php selecting bulk email and post

Tags: php, jquery, email, phpmailer

ive got over thousands my clients email in database.

sorting the email with php:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT email FROM user LIMIT 200");
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="emailList" class="useremail" value="'.$r['email'].'">';
endwhile;
```

anyone knows how to post the selected email only?. if possible with ajax jquery. well of course i will use phpmailer to post the email.

Answer (score 1):

```
how do i echo out random email
```

query

```
SELECT email FROM user ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200
```

Generally, using ORDER BY RAND() is not a good idea.
check here
http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 1):

You can `SELECT` random rows by using `RAND()`;

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT email FROM user ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200");
```

Your second question is not clear though, you will need to change the `value` of the checkbox to the email address or an id relating to that email, maybe like this:

```
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="emailList" class="useremail" value="'.$r['email'].'">';
endwhile;
```

You can then access checked values of `emailList` by using `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Or

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: i just updated my question with ur answer! what i mean was, there will be possible 200 emails `(checkbox->email address)`. and i want to check/select which email i want to post. and only selected email will be submited & posted. and i want to do it with jquery ajax. hope u get what i mean :)

Comment: I wrote this other day - it might be a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346171/ajax-get-data-from-php/5346253#5346253

Comment: thanks for the link jake! i understand to get if only one email selected. and how if i select more than 1 email. and how do i get those email value with ajax